# Resolve domain domain name during AD form login

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-4.0, active-directory

I have set up a logincontrol for my application to authenticate against AD.  It works well except it requires the user to type their username in such format:

username@domain.com

Is there a way to automatically append the domain name so the user doesnt have to type it or see it?

EDIT: Showing web.config.

```
<configuration>
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="ADConnectionString" connectionString="LDAP://domain.com/DC=domain,DC=com" />
</connectionStrings>
```

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms name=".ADAuthCookie" timeout="10" />
</authentication>

<authorization>
    <deny users="?" />
    <allow users="*" />
</authorization>


  <membership defaultProvider="domainCOMADMembershipProvider">
      <providers>
          <add
             name="domainCOMADMembershipProvider"
             type="System.Web.Security.ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider, System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0, 
         Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"
             connectionStringName="ADConnectionString"
             connectionUsername="hidden"
             connectionPassword="hidden"/>
      </providers>
  </membership>

<profile>
  <providers>
    <clear/>
    <add name="AspNetSqlProfileProvider" type="System.Web.Profile.SqlProfileProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" applicationName="/"/>
  </providers>
</profile>

<roleManager enabled="false">
  <providers>
    <clear/>
    <add name="AspNetSqlRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" applicationName="/" />
    <add name="AspNetWindowsTokenRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.WindowsTokenRoleProvider" applicationName="/" />
  </providers>
</roleManager>
```

Comment: Added.  I'm just using the standard forms auth against AD, nothing custom or fancy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [Login.Authenticate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.login.authenticate.aspx) event to override the default behavior and append the domain name.

Comment: is the authenticate event fired after the user is already authenticated though?  I want to keep the user from having to type "@domain.com".

Comment: No.  That is the method fired to *do* the authentication.